# Comparison between two codes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to rewrite a function: it gets in input a dataframe and does a gaussian fit of the distribution of every column, then substitutes every value below (in terms of absolute value) the threshold, set as n-times the std of the gaussian distribution of that column. Then, if asked, changes every value above the threshold with +/-1 according to its sign.

It looks like this:

```
def filter_signal(data_frame, nsigma = 5, bin_width = 0.5, flat = True):       
    #threshold dictionary for each column
    thr = {}
    
    # define gauss-function
    def gaussiana(x, a, mu, sigma):
        return a * np.exp(-(x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    
    #define substitution function (if Flat = True, uses +/-1)
    if flat:
        def subst(x, col):
            if x < -thr[col]:
                return -1
            if x > thr[col]:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    else:
        def subst(x,col):
            if -thr[col] < x < thr[col]:
                return 0
            else:
                return x
        
    #output dataframe
    output = pd.DataFrame(columns=data_frame.columns)
    
    #for cicle to repeat onver every column
    for col in data_frame.columns:
        # create histogram
        bins = int((data_frame[col].max() - data_frame[col].min())/bin_width)
        hist3, bin_edges3 = np.histogram(data_frame[col], bins=bins)
        bin_centers3 = (bin_edges3[:-1] + bin_edges3[1:]) / 2            

        #gaus fit
        popt3, pcov3 = curve_fit(gaussiana, bin_centers3, hist3)
        
        #add to the threshold dictionary and apply substitution on every column
        thr[col] = abs(nsigma * popt3[2])
        output[col] = data_frame[col].apply(subst, col=col)
        pass
    
    return output
```

This had a bit long execution time, but worked perfectly.

Now I'm trying to rewrite it using numpy which should be way faster. I wrote this:

```
def filter_signal_np(data_frame, nsigma = 5, bin_width = 0.5, flat = True):       #in input il dataframe da filtrare e il criterio di nsigma da applicare
    output = data_frame.copy()
    
    # define gauss function
    def gaussiana(x, a, mu, sigma):
        return a * np.exp(-(x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    

    for col in data_frame.columns:
        # create histogram
        column = data_frame[col]
        bins = int((column.max() - column.min())/bin_width)
        print(col, column.max())
        hist3, bin_edges3 = np.histogram(column, bins=bins)
        bin_centers3 = (bin_edges3[:-1] + bin_edges3[1:]) / 2 

        #gaussian fit
        popt3, pcov3 = curve_fit(gaussiana, bin_centers3, hist3)
        
        #substitution of the data below threshold
        index = np.where(column < nsigma * popt3[2])
        column[index[0]] = 0
        
        #subst of the data above threshold (only if Flat)
        if flat:
            column[np.invert(index[0])] = np.sign(column[np.invert(index[0])])
        
        #column becomes the output
        output[col] = column
    
    return output
```

However this second version doesn't work in two ways:
1)it modifies the input data (i don't know why)
2)it doesn't substitute data as it should: some columns have the whole data converted to 0 and the others have no changes, have any clue?

Comment: `column[index[0]] = 0` is here the same as `data_frame[col][index[0]] = 0` (because of `column = data_frame[col]`) which modifies `data_frame`.